# Why taking into account the polarization of photons doubles the available cells in phase space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, polarization

The volume in the 6D phase space available to photons whose frequency in the range between υ and υ+dυ is $$\frac{4\pi Vh³υ²dυ}{c³}$$ Why when taking into account the polarization of photons, this doubles the available volume to $\frac{8\pi Vh³υ²dυ}{c³}$?

Comment: It does not have to be seen as doubling the available volume. Really, it is a doubling of possible states. You can think of it as, instead of having one state per cell in phase space, you now can put two.